# one element doesn't completely stay on top of another

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

From front to back I want #elem, .hexagon, .circle. But the problem is circle's red color still stays on hexagon... z-index doesn't work too.

z-index makes difference in red color opacity but still color stays on hexagons. I want it gone completely behind hexagons.

I want red color of circle to stay behind the hexagons and i could see it in gaps between hexagons.

```js
let height = 0;
let index = 0;
let temp = false;
let left;
let topp = -21;
while (document.body.clientHeight <= innerHeight + 200) {
  for (let inde = 0, left = -40; inde < 25 || temp === true; inde++) {
    document.body.innerHTML += `<img id="h${index}" class="hexagon" src="hexagon1.png" 
    alt="">`
    const hexagon = document.querySelector(`#h${index}`);
    hexagon.style.left = left + "px";
    hexagon.style.top = topp + "px";
    left += 80;
    index++;
    if (inde == 24) {
      temp = false;
      topp += 61;
      height += 80;
      document.body.style.height = height + "px";
    }
  }
  for (let inde = 0, left = 0; inde < 25 || temp === false; inde++) {
    document.body.innerHTML += `<img id="h${index}" class="hexagon" src="hexagon1.png" 
    alt="">`;
    const hexagon = document.querySelector(`#h${index}`);
    hexagon.style.left = left + "px";
    hexagon.style.top = topp + "px";
    left += 80;
    index++;
    if (inde == 24) {
      temp = true;
      topp += 61;
      height += 80;
      document.body.style.height = height + "px";
    }
  }
}

const elem = document.querySelector("#elem");
let x = 0;
let el = false;
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  if (el) {
    document.body.removeChild(el);
  }
  const circle = document.createElement("div");
  circle.className = "circle";
  circle.style.left = e.offsetX + "px";
  circle.style.top = e.offsetY + "px";
  circle.style.transform = "translate(-50%,-50%)";
  document.body.appendChild(circle);
  el = circle;
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

.hexagon {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#elem {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 3;
}

.circle {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem"></div>
```

Comment: You need to set some `background-color` to `#elem` and `.hexagon`

Comment: Yes! It worked... thanks!

Comment: I didn't give layer to hexagon and #elem that's why circle was only element to stay on top.... it's like that right?

Comment: Since you didn't background on elem and hexagon they have transparent background and circles background is bleeding through.

Comment: for more information about position study this link https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp